# How to proceed with questions without an accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

I recently came across [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/199751/should-http-security-headers-be-configured-for-all-servers), which got bumped to the homepage, as it did not have an accepted answer.

The provided answer was very good, yet was not accepted. Why this is the case is unclear, although my best guess is that the person who originally asked the question simply did not care.

How should we proceed with these questions? Should they just be randomly bumped to the homepage for all eternity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions without upvoted answers get bumped to the homepage. The solution to keeping them from being bumped is to vote.

Comment: I must have mistakenly assumed that the reason they got bumped were because they did not have an accepted answer. Thank you for clarifying this.

Comment: No problem! Keep voting and keep answering!